# How to treat spaces in extracted links(rvest)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have extracted hyperlinks from a website. And I wish to scrape those further but those links contain spaces which normally should be replaced with %20. And I am getting a 404 error because of that. These are the hyperlinks from my output saved under the variable 'url':

```
[1] "https://csr.gov.in/companyprofile.php?year=FY 2014-15&CIN=U18109MH2006PLC262077.html"
[2] "https://csr.gov.in/companyprofile.php?year=FY 2014-15&CIN=L70101HR1963PLC002484.html"
[3] "https://csr.gov.in/companyprofile.php?year=FY 2014-15&CIN=L65910MH1986PLC165645.html"
[4] "https://csr.gov.in/companyprofile.php?year=FY 2014-15&CIN=U72200KA2002PLC030310.html"
```

And this is the code where I am getting an error:

```
map_df(url, function(i){ 
  page <- read_html(i)%>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table(fill = TRUE)})
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
 Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply substitute the spaces for "%20" symbols:

```r
tablist <- map(gsub(" ", "%20", url), function(i){ 
  read_html(i) %>%
  html_nodes("table")
})
```

Which results in:

```r
tablist
#> [[1]]
#> {xml_nodeset (6)}
#> [1] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [2] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [3] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [4] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [5] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [6] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> {xml_nodeset (6)}
#> [1] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [2] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [3] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [4] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [5] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [6] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> {xml_nodeset (6)}
#> [1] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [2] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [3] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [4] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [5] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [6] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> {xml_nodeset (6)}
#> [1] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [2] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [3] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [4] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [5] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
#> [6] <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" wid ...
```

Unfortunately the tables all seem to be empty on these pages, so you can't call `html_table` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way to do it is to use `URLencode()` function. It'd also replace other special characters in the URL to make the URL works:

```
urls <- 
  c(
    "https://csr.gov.in/companyprofile.php?year=FY 2014-15&CIN=U18109MH2006PLC262077.html",
    "https://csr.gov.in/companyprofile.php?year=FY 2014-15&CIN=L70101HR1963PLC002484.html",
    "https://csr.gov.in/companyprofile.php?year=FY 2014-15&CIN=L65910MH1986PLC165645.html",
    "https://csr.gov.in/companyprofile.php?year=FY 2014-15&CIN=U72200KA2002PLC030310.html"
  )

encoded_urls <- lapply(urls, function(url) URLencode(url))
```